# Django template filter for numbers

Tags: python, django, django-filters

I need such Django template filter:

```
1 > 01
2 > 02
10 > 10
```

Do you understand? I want to make 2 min length of the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perfect use case for [`stringformat`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#stringformat) built-in filter:

```
{{ value|stringformat:"02d" }}
```

Demo:

```
>>> from django.template import Template, Context, loader
>>> values = [1, 2, 10, 100]
>>> c = Context({'values': values})
>>>
>>> t = Template("""
... {% for value in values %}
...     {{ value }}, {{ value|stringformat:"02d" }}
... {% endfor %}""")
>>> print t.render(c)
    1, 01
    2, 02
    10, 10
    100, 100
```

Comment: Yep, thanks it works perfect!!! :)

Comment: @Q-bart just found that there was a similar thread, marked as a duplicate, but I'll keep the answer (since it has an example mostly). Thanks!